# Parse QueryString into strongly typed object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I know it can be done automatically;

```
class Query 
{ 
     public int?[] Id { get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Index(Query q)
{
}
```

Some QueryString `/index?id=10&id=11`

It works flawlessy.

But in some scenario I have only request available:

```
Reqest.RawUrl
```

It is possible to use built-in parsing to create query object?

```
Query q = SomeMagicStuff<Query>(Request.RawUrl);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is possible. If you using MVC you can use MVC `DefaultModelBinder` i write a function for this case:

```
public class MyModelBinder<T>
{
    private ModelBindingContext modelBindingContext = new ModelBindingContext();

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to get model from QueryString
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">HttpRequest</param>
    /// <returns>T model</returns>
    public static T GetModelFromQueryString(HttpRequest request)
    {
        modelBindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, typeof(T));
        modelBindingContext.ValueProvider = new NameValueCollectionValueProvider(request.QueryString, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        IModelBinder mb = new DefaultModelBinder();
        return (T)mb.BindModel(new ControllerContext(), modelBindingContext);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Method to get model from FormColletion
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="request">HttpRequest</param>
    /// <returns>T model</returns>
    public static T GetModelFromFormColletion(HttpRequest request)
    {
        modelBindingContext.ModelMetadata = ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, typeof(T));
        modelBindingContext.ValueProvider = new NameValueCollectionValueProvider(request.Params, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        IModelBinder mb = new DefaultModelBinder();
        return (T)mb.BindModel(new ControllerContext(), modelBindingContext);
    }
}
```

Note that there is 2 methods. They are differ only with `request.Params` and `request.QueryString`.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Serialize query string and deserialize to your class object

```
 JObject json;
 Request.RequestUri.TryReadQueryAsJson(out json);
 string sjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(json);
 Query query = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Query>(sjson);
```