# Datetime conversion of all url/query parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Datetimes with unspecified Kind are giving my endpoints some problems. So I want to apply a converter globally to make any unspecified kind datetimes to local. I was able to do this for all datetimes being read from json with `JsonConverter<DateTime>` but since url/query parameters aren't json they don't get the conversion. Is there a way to do this for url/query parameters as well before it hits the endpoint logic or do I need to do it in each endpoint?

Comment: Are you using MVC? You can use a custom `ModelBinder` if so... See also [Parse QueryString into strongly typed object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37703540/215552) and [Parse and modify a query string in .NET Core](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29992848/215552)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue can be solved by custom `model binding` which is a kind of `cross-cutting concerns`. The idea of `cross-cutting concerns` is to find a common extensibility point in a pipeline to inject some code to do something without repeating or spreading the code everywhere. So here you can use a custom `IModelBinder` which should always works. However as recommended by Microsoft, in this case you have a string representation of `DateTime`, you need to convert that to `DateTime`. This should be done with `TypeConverter` instead which is even simpler than using a custom `IModelBinder`. You can create a custom `TypeConverter` for your `DateTime` string (obtained from the query string, route data, ...) to deal with some specific format of `DateTime`.

Here is just an example:

```
public class CustomDateTimeConverter : TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string) || base.CanConvertFrom(context, sourceType);
    }
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return typeof(DateTime?).IsAssignableFrom(destinationType) || base.CanConvertTo(context, destinationType);
    }
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        //your custom logic to parse a DateTime from your specific format here
        //For a simple and funny example, I use the word "today"
        if(value?.ToString() == "today")
        {
            return DateTime.Today;
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
}
```

Now you need to register this custom type converter for `DateTime` such as in the `ConfigureServices` method in `Startup.cs` (can be put in static methods as well):

```
TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes(typeof(DateTime), new TypeConverterAttribute(typeof(CustomDateTimeConverter)));
```

Now suppose your model property (of `DateTime` or `DateTime?`) name is `Date`, the following query string should send the `DateTime.Today` to your model property:

```
?date=today
```